# my chrome theme is not being applied to incognito, its gray all of a sudden

Tags: google-chrome

I looked online and it said to go to `chrome://flags` and disable Enable Incognito brand consistency in desktop but when i went to chrome flags i can't find that option , please help me i can't use chrome anymore this grey color is driving me crazy

How to set some other theme in incognito mode? Currently, bar is so dark, that I can't clearly see anything. This is what I used to use:

In experimental (`chrome://flags/`) I enabled "Allow widgets to inherit native theme from its parent widget" function.
I installed a plain theme.
Starting today, it stopped working. After every problematic update, I always managed to find some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Experiments at chrome:flags can be removed at any time by the Chromium team. If there is no other option, you cannot do it! The whole purpose of having Incognito NTPs grey is identification, so think of it as a good thing!